# Follow path object goes to infinity and wont stop

Tags: modeling, objects, bezier-curves, constraints, path

I have been struggling for the past 2 hours to make an object follow a path. The problem is that the object doesn't stop at the end of the curve (doesn't matter if I use path or Bezier) it just goes beyond infinity. If u guys could help me with this problem I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 5):

1. add bezier path
2. add object
3. add object constraint "follow path" to object -> target: bezier path
4. Tap animate path
5. on bezierpath: Check "Clamp"

[image]